# How to get xargs not to eat double spaces

Tags: terminal, bash

I'm trying to process some files with double spaces in the name. It seems like xargs is removing spaces. Example

```
$ echo "foo  bar" | xargs -I {} echo "{}"
foo bar
```

Notice there's only 1 space between `foo` and `bar` but 2 were passed in. The example above works in Ubuntu 16.04 bash

Note I'm actually trying to process a list of files as in

```
cat list-of-files | xargs -I {} echo "{}"
```

`-O` doesn't work in this case as xargs sees the entire file as one filename.  Tried `-E '\n'` but that still ate the extra space

Comment: Try adding `-0` to the xargs command. This is likely a difference between GNU xargs (in Ubuntu) and BSD (on MacOS).

Comment: Actually, `xargs` (without `-0`) gets confused by *any* spaces (or certain other characters) in filenames. In your example, it actually sees "foo" and "bar" as two separate items (and then `echo` splices them together with a single space between). See [BashFAQ #20: How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) for a good collection of techniques.

Comment: sorry I should have been more specific. I have a list of files in a text file so `-0` isn't useful by itself. Maybe I need some other command to spit the file to insert `\0` for newlines?

Comment: @gman `tr '\n' '\0' < filenames.txt | xargs -0 ...`

Answer (score 4):

Here are 3 possibilities that may work for you:

### 1. BSD xargs

This is built in to MacOS, but will require you to quote the filenames in your `list-of-files`

```
$ more list-of-files
'file1'
'file2'
'file 3'
'file  4'
```

*note: I added the `-t` option in order to show the generated command before it executes.*

```
$ cat list-of-files | xargs -t -I {} echo "{}"
echo file1
file1
echo file2
file2
echo file 3
file 3
echo file  4
file  4
```

### 2. GNU xargs

GNU xargs is not installed on MacOS by default, but can be installed via homebrew (in the findutils package).

`brew install findutils`

Using GNU xargs via homebrew would not require you to quote the filenames, and would give the same result as using BSD xargs, and quoting the filenames (option 1, above).

### 3. find (instead of `list-of-files`)

Rather than using a file for your input, use the `find` command. Something like the following should work:

```
$ ls -laF file*
-rw-r--r--  1 sfederman  staff  0 Jun  7 22:53 file  4
-rw-r--r--  1 sfederman  staff  0 Jun  7 22:53 file 3
-rw-r--r--  1 sfederman  staff  0 Jun  7 22:53 file1
-rw-r--r--  1 sfederman  staff  0 Jun  7 22:53 file2

$ find . -name "file*" | xargs -0 -I {} echo "{}"
./file  4
./file 3
./file1
./file2
```

Or, avoiding xargs completely:

```
$ find . -name "file*" -exec echo "{}" \;
./file  4
./file1
./file2
./file 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a work around for your issue using `sed` to wrap each line of the file with double quotes.

```
sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/' < list-of-files | xargs -I {} echo {}
```

This also works with GNU `xargs`.

Comment: @user3439894 `{}` is a placeholder and any character(s) can be used as a placeholder. Quoting the placeholder isn't necessary. The redirection is optional.

Comment: I know that the `xargs` _option_ `−I replstr` can be `X` as you had it, however I used what was in the OP so as to avoid any confusion in comparing what was used in the OP and the other answer. The `<`, while optional, is totally unnecessary in this use case as `sed` is going to read the specified _file_, e.g. `list-of-files` after its _options_ and _command(s)_. If you're unhappy with the changes I've made, you obviously are free to revert it back to your original answer.

Comment: This will work as long as the input doesn't contain any double quotes.  A more general solution might be to backslash-escape any backslash, space, tab, single quote, or double quote character. `sed $'s/[ \t\\"\']/\\\\&/g'` (pardon the horrendous nested quoting!)